# Embed a view controller in a new navigation controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

How can I embed a new view controller in a navigation controller that already exist on the storyboard?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail? "Embed" in particular. What is the intended VC hierarchy? One navigation controller with two "roots"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You drag from the top of the Navigation Controller to the View Controller you want. Then select root view controller.

[image: screnshot1]

[image: screenshot 2]